# Error when invoking this.prisma.user.update() in NestJS UserService

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm facing an issue while trying to update a user using the `this.prisma.user.update()` method in a NestJS application. The code snippet that generates the error in `user.service.ts` is as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {}

  async editUser(userId: number, dto: EditUserDto) {
  console.log(userId);
    const user = await this.prisma.user.update({
      where: {
        id: userId,
      },
      data: {
        ...dto,
      },
    });
    

    delete user.hash;

    return user;
  }
}
```

`userId` in `console.log` returning JSON representation of a whole object, instead of getting the ID representation.

Here is the Prisma schema of this entity:

```
model User {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  email String @unique
  hash String
  firstName String?
  lastName String?

  cars Car[]

  @@map("users")
}
```

And the basic controller:

```
@UseGuards(JwtGuard)
@Controller('users')
export class UserController {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  @Get('current')
  getCurrent(@GetUser('') user: User) {
    return user;
  }

  @Patch()
  editUser(@GetUser('id') userId: number, @Body() dto: EditUserDto) {
    return this.userService.editUser(userId, dto);
  }
}
```

Logs:

> ```
> Argument id: Got invalid value
> ```

```
{
  id: 1,
  createdAt: new Date('2023-06-22T05:40:38.230Z'),
  updatedAt: new Date('2023-06-23T04:52:31.638Z'),
  email: 'test@test.com',
  firstName: 'testuser',
  lastName: null
}
```

> ```
> on prisma.updateOneUser. Provided Json, expected Int.
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Put('/:id')
editUser(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number, @Body() dto: EditUserDto) {
  return this.userService.editUser(id, dto);
}
```

Nestjs is a type-defining language. When receiving data from the client, you must specify its type. Although patch can be used for update operations, I believe put would be a better solution and here I get the id value with the path parameter. If you do an update like this, your problem will be gone. And here with the getuser decorator you can't just expect to get the id by pulling all the user value.

Comment: I tried this solution, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected, it returns 404 instead of 200. But when I pass the `user: User` object and access it using `user.id`, it returns the correct response, but it might not be the best solution in my scenario.
I'll need to investigate further or consider an alternative approach to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem today in editUser tests, it was about I was passing and objet and required integer. Given that, you couldn't just pass the value to the editUser service call. The method expects id of type number. I have user of type User (object). So I passed the .id property of your user, which contains the expected value.

```
//so User and Bookmark controllers gave errors this way:

// FOR THE USERS

@Patch()
editUser(
  @GetUser('id') userId: number,
  @Body() dto: EditUserDto,
) {
  return this.userService.editUser(userId, dto);
}


// FOR THE BOOKMARKS

@Get()
getBookmarks(@GetUser('id') userId: number) {
  return this.bookmarkService.getBookmarks(
    userId,
  );
} 


//FIXED THEM, THIS WAY

// FOR THE USERS

@Patch()
editUser(@GetUser('id') user: User, @Body() dto: EditUserDto) {
  return this.userService.editUser(user.id, dto);
}

// FOR THE BOOKMARKS

@Get()
getBookmarks(@GetUser('id') user: User) {
  return this.bookmarkService.getBookmarks(user.id);
}
```